# VirusTotal Api Usage?

Tags: c#

So i got this

```
public class VirusTotal
{
    public string APIKey;
    string scan = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/scan_file.json";
    string results = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/get_file_report.json";

    public VirusTotal(string apiKey)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        APIKey = apiKey;
    }

    public string Scan(string file)
    {
        var v = new NameValueCollection();
        v.Add("key", APIKey);
        var c = new WebClient() { QueryString = v };
        c.Headers.Add("Content-type", "binary/octet-stream");
        byte[] b = c.UploadFile(scan, "POST", file);
        var r = ParseJSON(Encoding.Default.GetString(b));
        if (r.ContainsKey("scan_id"))
        {
            return r["scan_id"];
        }
        throw new Exception(r["result"]);
    }

    public string GetResults(string id)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(id);
        var data = string.Format("resource={0}&key={1}", id, APIKey);
        var c = new WebClient();
        string s = c.UploadString(results, "POST", data);
        var r = ParseJSON(s);
        foreach (string str in r.Values)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
        if (r["result"] != "1")
        {
            throw new Exception(r["result"]);
        }
        return s;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> ParseJSON(string json)
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        json = json.Replace("\"", null).Replace("[", null).Replace("]", null);
        var r = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2).Split(',');
        foreach (string s in r)
        {
            d.Add(s.Split(':')[0], s.Split(':')[1]);
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

But were do i input the url i would awsume its the scan, but how do i retrive the scans back and that and start the scan proccess

sorry but im new in apis and i dont really get webclient thx for ur help

Comment: Instead of giving it an url to scan, you make a post request containing the file (see this simple PHP virustotal api: https://www.thewebhelp.com/php/scripts/virustotal-php-api/ ) , then later you ask again for a report on that file.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to specify any URLs here.

When you upload a file for scanning, you get back unique request ID generated by VirusTotal. That ID is a return value of `Scan` function. If you store this value in a variable and then specify it in a call to `GetResults` then you should get your results.

Code will look like:

```
VirusTotal vtObject = new VirusTotal("%Your_API_key_here%");
string resultID = vtObject.Scan("%your_file_name_here%");
string results = vtObject.GetResults(resultID);
```

Please also note that file scan takes some time, so you will most probably receive something like "Your file queued for scanning, come back later" in `results`. You may want to call `GetResults` subsequently after some time interval so you can get actual scan data after VT processes your file.

Comment: Im Still confused i puted my url in the your file name here + my api key in ur api key here

Comment: Do you want to scan a file from url? Then you need to either: 1) Download the file to the local HDD and specify the path in a call to `Scan` or 2) Use another function of VT API, spcifically designed for scanning URLs (see [documentation](https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/), part "Sending and scanning URLs")

Comment: I wanna scan a url, i dont wanna use webbrowser and i want it to be able to detect if its Detected or not