# How to go about implementing the VirusTotal API in a C# WPF desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, malware, scanning

So i currently have a C# WPF Desktop application in place, i want to be able to code a function where users can upload their files or URL in the app, where then the file will be scanned and generate an output of the outcome whether the file is malicious or not.

Heres a general code/idea that i want to accomplish:

```
var scanner = new AntiVirus.Scanner();
var result = scanner.ScanAndClean(@"c:\some\file\path.txt");
Console.WriteLine(result); // console output is "VirusNotFound".
```

I have done some research on this and found some links that may be useful for me as a guide to follow such as

https://code-examples.net/en/q/ee108

https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/

https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotalNet

but Im not sure whats the simplest and best method to coding this without too much complexity and code. I found this post that i think describes what i want to achieve in the least amount of code compared to the links above which may seem much more complex to code.
[VirusTotal Api Usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383553/virustotal-api-usage)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003895489-Get-Started

Answer (score -1):

Use xleaf.net library it enable easy webrequest with file attachments and etc